# Visualizing the full cross-correlation matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

When [plotting a cross-correlation matrix](http://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/many_pairwise_correlations.html) in `seaborn` is there any way to visualize the full matrix ? I know it's symmetric, but rendering the full matrix makes it easier to visually inspect it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently, though I have a more general purpose heatmap function in the works.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'mask' lines in the code. They are the ones that put empty values in the upper part of the matrix.

```
# Generate a mask for the upper triangle
mask = np.zeros_like(corr, dtype=np.bool)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True
```

This is what masks the upper triangle.